# VBA Excel, when I read from a text file into a (string) variable, why does it not read Carriage return and line feed characters (0d 0a)

Tags: excel, vba, file

I am working on a macro that takes data from a textbox and writes it to a file. The data includes carriage return/Linefeed characters. At a later stage, I need to read the data from the file and put it back in the textbox in exactly the same form. When I do this, the Cr/Lf characters (0d 0a) are missing. I have established that they are written to the file but not read back. I am using the following snippet to write the file:

```
Print #1, Temstg
Close #1
```

and reading it using the following snippet:

```
Do Until EOF(1)

    Line Input #1, T
    Temstg = Temstg & T
    
Loop
    
Close #1
```

Where am I going wrong

Rob

Comment: Change `Temstg = Temstg & T` to `Temstg = Temstg & T & vbCrLf`

Comment: `Line Input` doesn't include the newline character(s)

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment `Line Input` considers newline character as the separator for a new line. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/line-inputstatement) is the documentation.

The following code reads the complete text file in one shot including newline characters.

```
Sub ReadFIle()
    Dim fileName As String: fileName = "C:\temp\yourfile.txt"
    
    Dim fileContent As String
    Dim File As Integer: File = FreeFile
    
    Open fileName For Input As #File
    fileContent = Input(LOF(File), File)
    
    Close #File
    
    ' example how to split the file in lines then
    Dim vDat As Variant
    vDat = Split(fileContent, vbNewLine)
    
End Sub
```

[Reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/input-function) on Input function